# How do I use `member val` in object expressions in fsharp?

Tags: f#

I have an interface in F# (generated from some typescript) that looks like this:

```
type [<AllowNullLiteral>] AppOptions =
    abstract credential: Admin.Credential.Credential option with get, set
    abstract databaseAuthVariableOverride: Object option with get, set
    abstract databaseURL: string option with get, set
    abstract storageBucket: string option with get, set
    abstract projectId: string option with get, set
```

I thought that the easiest way to create an instance of that type would be to create a simple object expression, but I can't get it to work. Isn't  `member val` allowed in object expression? If not, what is the easiest way to create a simple instance of an interface with getters and setters on all properties? This is what I tried that didn't work:

```
let options = 
    { new Admin.AppOptions with
        member val credential: Admin.Credential.Credential option = None with get, set 
        member val databaseAuthVariableOverride: obj option = None with get, set 
        member val databaseURL: string option = None with get, set 
        member val databaseURL: string option = None with get, set 
        member val projectId: string option = None with get, set 
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think member var is in the object expression spec only the long form properties like this are allowed:

```
let options =
    let mutable credential = None 
    let mutable databaseAuthVariableOverride = None
    let mutable databaseURL = None
    let mutable storageBucket = None
    let mutable projectId = None
    { new AppOptions with
        member x.credential with get() = credential and set v = credential <- v
        member x.databaseAuthVariableOverride with get() = databaseAuthVariableOverride and set v = databaseAuthVariableOverride <- v
        member x.databaseURL with get() = databaseURL and set v = databaseURL <- v
        member x.storageBucket with get() = storageBucket and set v = storageBucket <- v
        member x.projectId with get() = projectId and set v = projectId <- v
    }
```

Which would project C# like code by the compiler like this:

```
[assembly: FSharpInterfaceDataVersion(2, 0, 0)]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.0.0.0")]
[CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.Module)]
public static class _
{
    [Serializable]
    [AllowNullLiteral]
    [CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.ObjectType)]
    public interface AppOptions
    {
        override FSharpOption<object> credential
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        override FSharpOption<object> databaseAuthVariableOverride
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        override FSharpOption<string> databaseURL
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        override FSharpOption<string> storageBucket
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        override FSharpOption<string> projectId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

[See sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgPg9gDgUwHYAIDKBPCAXBBbAWAChsNEUBtAHgEFhgYB3AOQFd6AZAS1wCcBDYAD4Auihpw4AeTjYuMJBBQBeYinUp+AIxwCAxthR7eCACbI5gkCilaAVggMp4chSkY8AFigDmCbAA0KBD+ahrauvxOpvzY2vwhNKzYngBq/Lxc2sAIUgBuCLyZ5ta2Dk4u8qgeKb7+QSHYYeoR2PqGMXFaCQgAqgBKHNa6XEg+zrJV7l51gcGhRBqaOm1RhjgwAn4AQqx6ANb+w22j45VuNd5+c43Ny5FOcLww5dgAkqbHmWMTrtUz1waC2IeBgpnYCBQuBwKhQdxyhnOihUdyWCJQeGS2UhxjMFiywFhzAUkNRGnRmK6ORQnXiiWSaQyWS0OXyhWKkOUKGJSAQZPUFKxLMhtO6IQGHCJJP5KEFVMhGy2CF2B38Ut5Mrl2JQTxejnepnVfMWSw0AG8ULzGOJJDI/kpLjKlnh8FpCigAB4AOlx5iQlkJl1mAAoAJSw334wSaJCGxooPIRkx+gMoKgAWgTTo0Lrwbt4nq9op6SRS6Uy2LZRS45mmtWuYdhxfpZaZlYK1dr/Fj80Mia5zYQpcZFeFVY5aczeWz6lz+cLg4ldau/kbA9idL6gxjcbV/ZpG7FW8lGazJtNprn7u9iv4Oz2h0MQYb4a5t/vqsM3d3fdh7+VD5qqe07nheOauteXq6q8HzLiGr46s8MGGt+vYJrC0H6rBwEygAvhoQA=)

A normal type is probably more succinct here:

```
    type t() = 
     interface AppOptions with
         member val credential = None with get, set
         member val databaseAuthVariableOverride = None with get, set 
         member val databaseURL = None with get, set 
         member val storageBucket = None with get, set 
         member val projectId = None with get, set
```